# Undefined offset from my checkbox form

Tags: php, html, checkbox

The following function works fine despite having the "Undefined offset" error but i need to debug it still. Can someone help me spot where the error is?

This is the form :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM application WHERE Shortlist_status = 1 AND Interview_datetime !=  '' AND Email_checked ='' ORDER BY Candidate_id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

<input type="hidden" name="can_id[]" value=<?php echo $canid ?>>
<input type="hidden" name="job_id[]" value=<?php echo $jobid ?>>

(Some codes)

<input name="email[]" id="id" type="checkbox" value="1">
}
```

This is the form handling:

```
foreach ($_POST['can_id'] as $i => $candidate_id) {
$job_id = $_POST['job_id'][$i];

$email = $_POST['email'][$i];

$insertQuery = "UPDATE application SET Email_checked = '$email' WHERE Candidate_id = $candidate_id AND Job_id = $job_id";
$inserted = mysqli_query($link, $insertQuery) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}

if($inserted)
{
    $message = 'Application successfully update <br><a href="interview.php">Manage Candidate</a>';; 
}
else
{
  $message = 'Application failed <br><a href="interview.php">Manage Candidate</a>';
}
echo $message;
```

Comment: Look at the error message. It tells you **exactly** where the error occurred (file and line number). You should be able to find it by yourself.

Comment: "but i need to debug it still" Well, go ahead, you'll be able to solve it

Comment: Oh yeah forget to mentioned the the error code is at line 9 which is my "$email = $_POST['email'][$i];" no idea where i went wrong there and the error only appear for the first time and subsequently not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you described the error in your comments, I would guess that the problem can be solved like this:

```
$email = isset($_POST['email'][$i]) ? $_POST['email'][$i] : "otherValue";
```

Replace `"otherValue"` with whatever you need if it is not set (probably `"0"`)

Comment: It solved the problem! Sorry but could explain to me the reason behind the solution because i am confuse on why it appear despite the data still pass through and why only the first time?

Comment: I believe that checkboxes don't populate `$_POST` when they are not checked. It has been a while since I did that kind of coding, it would be worth double checking by printing all of `$_POST` after a submission

Answer (score -1):

```
$email = isset($request->email[$i]) ? $request->email[$i] : 0;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!